# In a category with binary products, every strong epimorphism is an epimorphism.

Tags: category-theory, epimorphisms

I can't prove the title proposition. So let $f$ be a strong epimorphism of a category with binary products. Let $u,v$ be morphisms such that uf=vf. I want to prove that $u=v$. I consider the commutative square $(1,1)\circ uf=(u,v)\circ f$. Since $f$ is a strong epimorphism and $(1,1)$ is a monomorphism, by definition of strongness there is a unique $t$ such that $tf=uf$ and $(1,1)\circ t=(u,v)$. It is obvious that both $u$ and $v$ make the triangle $tf=uf$ commute. What I can't understand is why both $u$ and $v$ make commute the triangle $(1,1)\circ t=(u,v)$.

Comment: I don't understand the question, to my knowledge "epimorphism" is part of the definition of "strong epmorphism". See the nLab : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strong+epimorphism

Comment: @Max There is a definition of strong epi including epicness, and that is clear to me, but there is another not including epicness. In this second case, you can prove that strong epi implies epi, provided the category has binary products.

Comment: Could you then clarify your definition in the question ?

Comment: @Max it is the same you have, without epimorphism, so a strong epimorphism is a morphism (not an epi, just a morphism) $f$  such that for every commutative square $mu=vf$ with $m$ a mono, $\exists t$ such that $tf=u$ and $mt=vf$.

Comment: Ok, well then Alex was quicker to answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that in a category with binary products, if a map $f\colon A\to B$ is orthogonal to every monomorphism, then $f$ is an epimorphism.

In fact, as your argument shows, it's enough to assume that $C\times C$ exists for every object $C$ and that $f$ is orthogonal to the diagonal map $(1,1)\colon C\to C\times C$ for every object $C$. Better, we only need that $f$ has the left lifting property with respect to $(1,1)$, meaning we don't have to assume that the diagonal filler is unique.

Following your argument, with the commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B\\
@V{uf = vf}VV @VV{(u,v)}V \\
C @>{(1,1)}>> C\times C
\end{CD}$$

the lifting property gives us some map $t\colon B\to C$ such that $(u,v) = (1,1)\circ t$. Now consider the compositions with $\pi_1,\pi_2\colon C\times C\to C$: $$u = \pi_1\circ (u,v) = \pi_1\circ (1,1)\circ t = t = \pi_2\circ (1,1)\circ t = \pi_2 \circ (u,v) = v.$$

Another way to put it: $(u,v) = (1,1)\circ t = (t,t)$, so $u = t$ and $v = t$, since the map $\mathrm{Hom}(B,C)\times \mathrm{Hom}(B,C)\to \mathrm{Hom}(B,C\times C)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Just a quick remark to add that the relaxing from _orthogonal_ to _only LLP_ is completely for free: a lifting in a square with a mono on the right is necessarily unique (by definition of a mono).